# 'Cannot access secondary GPU' error with Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I tried to run

```
optirun glxgears
```

and I got this output:

```
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.
Please[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Could you paste the full error using the code sample (`<$>` icon) tool? That way we can know the full problem without askubuntu breaking the formatting :)

Comment: @lkjoel <$ optirun glxgears>
[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled. (click edit to see the format i am new to ask)

Answer (score 3):

**So to get Bumblebee to work**

a) Run the following command to find out the BusID for your Nvidia graphics card:

```
 lspci | grep NVIDIA
```

The BusID is the number in the beginning of the line returned by the command above. Here's how the output for the command above looks like on my laptop:

```
 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev ff)
```

The BusID is the number in bold, "01:00.0" in my case.

b) Now we'll have to add the BusID to /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia and for this, we'll open the file as root with a text editor (I'll use Gedit in the command below):

```
 sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

And in this file, in the "Device" section, add the following:

```
    BusID "PCI:YOUR_BUS_ID"
```

Replacing "YOUR_BUS_ID" with the BusID returned by the command used under step a). For me (remember, for you, the BusID may be different), this line looks like this:

```
  BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
```

Then, restart your system and Bumblebee should work so when you want to run an application or game on your Nvidia card, use:

```
 optirun APP_OR_GAME
 optirun glxspheres
```

[Help > W E B U P D 8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html) Check Bumblebee Section

Comment: i am having the same prob ...this fixed it

Comment: This fixed it for me. In fact, the config file specifically states that it's needed for Ubuntu 13.04, which I'm using. May not be applicable to the original question, but might help others.

Comment: did not fix it for me :( .. using arch

Comment: @philx_x are you getting the same error. After making a change try rebooting

Answer (score 0):

I ran into *exactly* the same issue just minutes ago on my Dell e6420.

Turns out there is a [bug report](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/182) in the Bumblebee git repo for this.

The solution given there, to delete the thinkpad conf file worked for me (strange since I have a Dell latitude and not thinkpad)

```
sudo rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-current-thinkpad-t420s.conf
```

Comment: rm: cannot remove `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-current-thinkpad-t420s.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: could you post the output of doing an ls in that directory, ie.  `sudo ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Comment: uptikool@fenrir:~$ cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
uptikool@fenrir:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls
10-evdev.conf             50-synaptics.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf
11-evdev-quirks.conf      50-vmmouse.conf
11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-wacom.conf
uptikool@fenrir:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$

Comment: ok, thats the same as I have. Could you provide some more information in your question about which version of ubuntu you are using?, what you have already done so far (eg. which PPA's you have added), etc.

Comment: i am using 12.04 and i followed these instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee i recently switched over from fedora

Comment: What happened next? Same story happening with me...I hate optimus