# How Do I Get optirun to Work on 16.04?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire E5-573G laptop, which apparently uses Optimus and doesn't have a BIOS option to switch between integrated and discreet graphics. I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/760878) to try to get my NVIDIA GeForce 940M to work using `nvidia-364`. While I can use my card by executing `# prime-select nvidia` and relogging, Xorg crashes upon the next logout, reboot, or shutdown, even if I first execute `# prime-select intel`. Therefore, I'd like to use my card only through `optirun` (or `primusrun`; I haven't been able to find how the two differ).

The first time I try to use `optirun`, I receive the following error message:

```
$ optirun glxgears
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":8".
```

All subsequent times, I receive these:

```
$ optirun glxgears
[   61.760218] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) 

[   61.760244] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I haven't been able to find any leads on the first error message, but as for the second set, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/285638/274792), which I followed only to discover my `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` already had the correct line:

```
$ lspci|grep NVIDIA
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)

$ grep BusID /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia 
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
    BusID "PCI:04:00:0"
```

I also found [a relevant thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036010), but adding `acpi=force` to the boot parameters did not solve the problem.

I've also tried `nvidia-361`; the system would not boot with `acpi=force` but otherwise exhibited the same issues as `nvidia-364`, `nvidia-367`, and `nvidia-370` (all of which I've tried). Nouveau also emits the same error messages. For what it's worth, I've noticed leaving a 3D application running while not the focused window eventually crashes Xorg, regardless of whether it's using integrated or discreet graphics or even of if I have Bumblebee installed.

I realize NVIDIA provides terrible support for Optimus on Linux, but any help getting my card working reasonably well would be much appreciated. I know I could just uninstall Bumblebee and use integrated graphics, but that doesn't answer this question.

Comment: I am facing similar issues. I have a Clevo laptop that does not have the ability to switch between onboard and discrete graphics. I am struggling to get the display drivers working properly. One suggestion that I can give is to include nouveau.modeset=0 in the grub, thereby disabling the nouveau drivers. That should at least take care of the frequent crashes and lockups.

Comment: any luck so far?

Comment: Oh, wow; it's been awhile. So, yes, my system is working; however, I don't exactly know why. I'm currently just using the NVIDIA driver and switch between integrated and discreet with PRIME. (I almost exclusively use integrated graphics to save power.) There are a few glitches with discreet (e.g. not being able to shut down while charging), but, for the most part, it works. I'll have to test trying to get a fresh install to work when I have some time in a few weeks.